# Setting Long in java jni call

Tags: java, java-native-interface

I want to return microseconds from linux as java only has wall clock times to millisecond accuracy on systems with a monotonic clock.

My exposure to jni is limited so apologies if it's a silly question.

I believe I can either make a call in the c layer to gettimeofday and return the value as jlong:

```
private native long getMicros();
```

Or perhaps alternatively take a pointer to an address and then write the value to this address:

```
private native void getMicros(Long ptr);
```

The latter throws up lots of questions in my mind like "how does c know what the binary format of jlong is" and "how would I even do this!".

I just wondered if the latter might be faster than returning a value back across the jni layer.

Any thoughts most welcome.

Answer (score 0):

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#nanoTime()

*"Returns the current value of the most precise available system timer, in nanoseconds.
This method can only be used to measure elapsed time and is not related to any other notion of system or wall-clock time. The value returned represents nanoseconds since some fixed but arbitrary time (perhaps in the future, so values may be negative). This method provides nanosecond precision, but not necessarily nanosecond accuracy. No guarantees are made about how frequently values change. Differences in successive calls that span greater than approximately 292 years (2<sup>63</sup> nanoseconds) will not accurately compute elapsed time due to numerical overflow.*

*For example, to measure how long some code takes to execute:"*

```
   long startTime = System.nanoTime();
   // ... the code being measured ...
   long estimatedTime = System.nanoTime() - startTime;
```